# Azure Redis Cache VS Application Cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, caching

### [ Azure Redis Cache ]

```
ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(string.Format("{0},abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password={1}", "reditCacheEndpoint", "reditCachePassword"));

IDatabase cache = connection.GetDatabase();

cache.StringSet("time", DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

**Pros**

Available from all your programs in Azure

Doesn't effect the performance of the application

**Cons**

Expensive

Slower

### [ Application Cache ]

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["time"] = DateTime.Now;
```

**Pros**

Faster

Free

**Cons**

Can only be used in your current app

Effects the performance of the application

---

I don't really see the reason to why you should use Azure Redis Cache instead of application cache.

If you have problems with the performance due to the cache taking up too much resouces, you can always add more power to your app, instead of scaling up your cache which would be more expensive.

Azure Redis Cache is nice when you need to use it for more than one service, but mostly I only need caching for one service.

**Why should I use Azure Redis Cache?**

Please add more pros & cons if you feel like i forgot something important.

Comment: I think the more important reason is, if you are planning your application for scalability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is more than just a key / value store. It supports many [data types](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) like Sorted Sets, Lists, HashSets, Strings etc. If your application needs to use the likes of such, you will benefit from Redis.

If your application is going to be on-premises accessing Redis in the cloud, it is bound to be slower in terms of latency than running Redis on your local machine or the Application cache.

Redis has in-built session state or output-cache providers that help to quickly wire up your websites with your Azure Redis Cache.

An application cache works just fine if you have one instance of your application. As soon as you scale this out, you need to have a distributed cache. At such times, Redis in VMs or Azure Redis Cache will be a solution you should consider.

Last, but not the least, if your application and Redis Cache are in the same azure region, you could get around 1 ms latencies or less for most of your requests, if you follow some of the best practices on connection management and payload sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Redis because it's not only a cache for your objects, but you can also cache the output of your pages. Also, Redis is replicated on Azure Servers, which means that you won't lose state, in case of rebooting or any other problem. I strongly recommend the use of Redis Cache ( Azure Redis Cache or Redis inside a Virtual Machine)

Comment: Page output caching can also be used for your pages in mvc using the OutputCache attribute above your action. It's nice that you don't lose state in case of rebooting or any other problem but I don't see me paying for this service..